# Selentium can't find an element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

everyone.

I've got a task to find needed element on the page and put it in every place, where @ sign is present. I can get into page, but can't find any of elements. 
Here's my code.

```
driver.get("https://plastinfo.ru/trade/sell/raw/1944506/")
p_links = driver.find("a")  
for link in p_links:
  print ("URL: " +link.attr("href"))
  print ("URL: " +link.attr("href"))
```

Comment: why do you use tag `python-requests` if you use `Selenium` ?

Comment: didn't you see error message when you run it ? You should see error message when you run in console/terminal because `driver` doesn't have `find` but `find_element_by_tag_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before getting attributes, everything must be loaded. So, after `driver.get` you can add strings:

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
```

Also, check documentation for correct getting attributes.